# How can I get a long text fit in a smaller DIV, wrapping itself in a new line if necessary?

Tags: html, css

I can make the text fit inside the div?

```
<div>
 Hello! This a long text, but I'd like it to fit the div's width
</div>
```

So far, I've used **max-width:100px**, expecting the text to be wrapped to a new line. But, what I've gotten so far is a long text appearing above its containet and overfilling other containers.

It's looks like, just using max-width, is not enough.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using `&nbsp;` characters instead of spaces, the line will overflow.

Also, check if the [white-space attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-CSS1-20080411/#white-space) is set to "normal" and not "nowrap".

Answer (score 3):

`width:100px;` should do it, depending on what other properties are set on the div.

Comment: looks fine to me... I've added a border to make it clear. http://jsfiddle.net/nathan/vCcGU/1/ If it's not working for you, what browser are you using?

Comment: I guess that's have to do with the other settings above that div. In fact, this div is located inside a li/ul/ whic is located inside a Jquery-ui tab, which is finaly located inside a floated div. I guess I need to go throug all of that to found why things are not going as expected.